# Customizing pdf output of dblatex

Tags: xml, latex, xslt, docbook, dblatex

I am writing a report using Docbook and i want to customize the way that dblatex converts Docbook to Pdf. [This page](http://dblatex.sourceforge.net/doc/sec-custom-latex.html) is supposed to document this issue but it really doesn't help me. How can i learn how the latex style package works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If learning LaTeX is indeed your problem then please go to http://www.latex-project.org/guides/ and read up on all the good documents there.